# php curl - ошибка из консоли Received HTTP/0.9 when not allowed

Tags: php, curl

Всем привет!
Есть php файл который отправляет curl post запрос на сторонний сервер во внутренней сети. Когда я запускаю этот файл из браузера - все работает, но когда запускаю из консоли то curl возвращает ошибку "Received HTTP/0.9 when not allowed". Причем не важно по какому адресу уходит запрос, на любой адрес одна и та же ошибка.

Заголовки отправляются одинаковые, что из браузера, что из консоли.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас скорее всего используются разные конфиги php.ini на веб-сервере и в консоли. А может быть и вовсе разные версии php. Скомпилируйте curl без ключа `http0.9.d`. Это исправит проблему.